# Image not constrained by parent div height, only width

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

my gatsby image is correctly constrained by width of the parent div, but not by the height property.

Width of image will not exceed the parent div (pink border):

[image]

However, if i increase browser size, the height of image goes beyond parent div (pink border):

[image]

Below is the code - how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

```
    <div 
  style={{
    display: `flex`,
    justifyContent: `flex-start`,
    borderStyle: `solid`,
    borderColor: `blue`,
    height:`70vh`,
    width:`100%`,
    marginTop: `3rem`
}}>
  <div className="imageContainer" 
    style={{
      width:`50%`,
      height:`100%`,
      borderStyle: `solid`,
      borderColor: `pink`,
  }}>
    <StaticImage
      src="../images/about.jpg"
      layout="constrained"
      width={1200}
      height={1100}
      quality={90}
      formats={["auto", "webp", "avif"]}
      alt="home image"
      style={{ 
        marginBottom: 0,
      }}
    />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want the image inside the pink border always follow the width and the height of the pink border div?

If yes, I think you can achieve it with this css below, add it to StaticImage className props.

```
.static-image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! i added this to the style={{}} props inside the image call